# Combining Tables of Different Schema based on ID in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with tables:

```
Demographics, with Schema:
"MRN", "Demographics","MaritalDescription" ,"DOB" ,"PCCCode" ,"DeceasedIND" ,"Death Date" ,"RaceDescription" ,"LanguageDescription" ,"SexDescription");

ED_Visit, with Schema: 
"MRN" , "VisitNo" , "AdmitTime" , "HospService" , "VisitStatus" , "VisitTime" , "Location" , "Clinic" , "Pt Type" , "Pt Status" , "EDSeverityDescription" , "EDDisp" , "Code" , "Description" );
```

I want to select all the records from ED_Visits which match on MRN with Demographics and merge them to Demographics.

I have tried:

```
SELECT VisitNo , AdmitTime , HospService , VisitStatus , VisitTime , Location , Clinic , "Pt Type", "Pt Status", EDSeverityDescription , EDDisp , Code , Description 
FROM ED_Visits
INNER JOIN Demographics ON ED_Visits.MRN = Demographics.MRN
UNION
SELECT MaritalDescription, DOB, PCCCode, DeceasedIND, "Death Date", RaceDescription, LanguageDescription, SexDescription  
FROM Demographics 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ED_Visits ON Demographics.MRN = ED_Visits.MRN;
```

Comment: You should consider using some formatting in order to make your question more readable.

Comment: Show the desired output.